# Automation error Excel 2010 from Delphi

Tags: delphi, excel, automation, excel-2010

Does anybody know why the following code does not work with Excel 2010 (*Home and Small Business Office Edition*) ¿?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rango : OleVariant;
  ExcelObject : TExcelApplication;
  ExcelWorksheet : TExcelWorksheet;
  LCID : integer;

begin

  try
    ExcelObject := TExcelApplication.Create (self);
    LCID := LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT;

    ExcelObject.Workbooks.Add(EmptyParam, LCID);

    ExcelWorksheet := TExcelWorksheet.Create(ExcelObject);
    ExcelWorksheet.ConnectTo(ExcelObject.Worksheets.Item [1] as _Worksheet);

    rango := ExcelWorksheet.Range['B2','B2'];
    rango.Font.size := 16;
    rango.Font.Bold := True;
    rango.Value2 := 'test';

    ExcelObject.Visible[lcid] := true;

  except
    on e: exception do
      showmessage(e.message);

  end;

end;
```

A "Not registered class" exception is shown while adding a workbook: "ExcelObject.Workbooks.Add(EmptyParam, LCID);"

This works fine with Office 2010 Proffesional Edition (and older Office Editions) but not with Home and Small Business Edition 2010 Edition.

Comment: "An exception is shown" is not really helpful to understand what's going on.  Consider editing your question to add the message associated with the raised exception.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late but I've been fighting with this same error the last two days and finally figured it out (I think). The error is misleading due to crappy error handling in the component.

The clue I had was that it worked perfectly in a different test application on the same machine - so it wasn't a class registration issue.

I get the error (in several places) if I don't have things connected properly. In your case you probably need to do the CONNECT.

E.g.

```
ExcelObject := TExcelApplication.Create (self);
ExcelObject.Connect;
```

I've also seen this if you forget to do a ConnectTo call to connect the interfaces together.

E.g.

```
XlWorkBook.ConnectTo(XlApp.ActiveWorkbook);
```

Hope this helps someone else.